# Need assistance with SAP CAP project: Adding Value Help for Watering Events in Plant Creation/Modification Screen"

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cap

I'm currently working on a SAP CAP (Cloud Application Programming) project where I've implemented a service (FarmboService) with entities such as Plants, Garden, WateringEvent, and associations between them. In my UI application, specifically in the Plant creation/modification screen, I'm trying to add a field that allows users to choose from a list of Watering Events as occurrences for a plant. The challenge is that each plant can have multiple watering event occurrences.

I've provided relevant portions of my CDS annotations and UI application code in the question details. I need guidance on how to implement a Value Help for the Watering Events in this context and allow multiple selections for a single plant.

Any assistance or insights into achieving this functionality would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

This introduction provides a brief overview of the problem, mentions the technologies involved, and highlights the specific challenge you're seeking help with.

here's my schema.cds

```
namespace my.farmbot;
using { cuid } from '@sap/cds/common';

entity Plants : cuid {
    key ID : Integer;
    garden : Association to Garden;
    radius : Double;
    x : Double;
    y : Double;
    name : String;
    wateringEvents : Association to many PlantWateringAssociation on wateringEvents.plant = $self;
}

entity Garden {
    key ID : Integer;
    name : String;
    plants : Association to many Plants on plants.garden = $self;
}
entity PlantWateringAssociation : cuid {
    key ID : Integer;
    plant : Association to Plants;
    wateringEvent : Association to WateringEvent;
}

entity WateringEvent: cuid {
   key ID: Integer;
    WateringType: String;
    Occurrence: Integer;
    createdAt: DateTime;
    createdBy: String;
    modifiedAt: DateTime;
    modifiedBy: String;
    plants : Association to many PlantWateringAssociation on plants.wateringEvent = $self;
}
```

farmbot-service.cds

```
using my.farmbot as my from '../db/level';

service FarmboService {

    entity Plants @( 
        Capabilities : {
            InsertRestrictions : {
                $Type : 'Capabilities.InsertRestrictionsType',
                Insertable : true 
            },
            UpdateRestrictions : {
                $Type : 'Capabilities.UpdateRestrictionsType',
                Updatable : true 
            },
            DeleteRestrictions : {
                $Type : 'Capabilities.DeleteRestrictionsType',
                Deletable : true
            }
        }
    ) as SELECT from my.Plants ;

    annotate Plants with @odata.draft.enabled;

    entity Garden @(
        Capabilities : {
            InsertRestrictions : {
                $Type : 'Capabilities.InsertRestrictionsType',
                Insertable : true 
            },
            UpdateRestrictions : {
                $Type : 'Capabilities.UpdateRestrictionsType',
                Updatable : true 
            },
            DeleteRestrictions : {
                $Type : 'Capabilities.DeleteRestrictionsType',
                Deletable : false
            }
        }
    ) as SELECT from my.Garden;

    annotate Garden with @odata.draft.enabled;

     entity WateringEvent @( 
        Capabilities : {
            InsertRestrictions : {
                $Type : 'Capabilities.InsertRestrictionsType',
                Insertable : true 
            },
            UpdateRestrictions : {
                $Type : 'Capabilities.UpdateRestrictionsType',
                Updatable : true 
            },
            DeleteRestrictions : {
                $Type : 'Capabilities.DeleteRestrictionsType',
                Deletable : false
            }
        }
    ) as SELECT from my.WateringEvent;

     entity PlantWateringAssociation as SELECT from my.PlantWateringAssociation;
}
```

app/plants/annotations.cds

```
using FarmboService as service from '../../srv/farmbot-service';

annotate service.Plants with @(
    UI          : {
        Identification : [{Value: name}],
        SelectionFields: [
            name,
        ],
        LineItem       : [
            {Value: ID,
                Label : '{i18n>PlantID}'},
            {Value: name,
                Label : '{i18n>name}'},
            {Value: radius, Criticality: level,
                Label : '{i18n>radius}' },
            {Value: garden.name,
                Label : '{i18n>GardenName}'},
            {Value : wateringEvents.wateringEvent.WateringType,
                Label : '{i18n>Type}'},
            {Value : wateringEvents.wateringEvent.Occurrence,
                Label : '{i18n>Occurence}'},  
        ],
        
        HeaderInfo     : {
            TypeName      : '{i18n>Plant}',
            TypeNamePlural: '{i18n>Plants}',
            Title         : {Value: name},
            Description   : {Value: garden.name}
        },
    }
);


annotate service.Plants with {
    ID     @title: '{i18n>PlantID}';
    name   @title: '{i18n>name}';
    radius @title: '{i18n>radius}';
    garden @title: '{i18n>garden}';
};


annotate service.Plants with @(
    UI.FieldGroup #GeneratedGroup1: {
        $Type: 'UI.FieldGroupType',
        Data : [
             {
                $Type: 'UI.DataField',
                Value: ID,
                Label : '{i18n>PlantID}',
            },
            {
                $Type: 'UI.DataField',
                Value: name,
                Label : '{i18n>name}',
            },
            {
                $Type: 'UI.DataField',
                Value: radius,
                Label : '{i18n>radius}',
            },
            {
                $Type: 'UI.DataField',
                Label: '{i18n>X}',
                Value: x,
            },
            {
                $Type: 'UI.DataField',
                Label: '{i18n>Y}',
                Value: y,
            },
            {
                $Type: 'UI.DataField',
                Label: '{i18n>garden}',
                Value: garden_ID,
            },
             {
                $Type: 'UI.DataField',
                Label: '{i18n>Occurrence}',
                Value: wateringEvents.wateringEvent.Occurrence,
            },
             {
                $Type: 'UI.DataField',
                Label: '{i18n>Type}',
                Value: wateringEvents.wateringEvent.WateringType,
            },

        ],
    },
    UI.Facets                     : [{
        $Type : 'UI.ReferenceFacet',
        ID    : 'GeneratedFacet1',
        Label : '{i18n>GeneralInformation}',
        Target: '@UI.FieldGroup#GeneratedGroup1',
    }, ],
    
);

annotate service.Plants with {
    garden @(Common.ValueList : {
            $Type : 'Common.ValueListType',
            CollectionPath : 'Garden',
            Parameters : [
                {
                    $Type : 'Common.ValueListParameterInOut',
                    LocalDataProperty : garden_ID,
                    ValueListProperty : 'ID',
                },
            ],
        },
        Common.ValueListWithFixedValues : true
)};

annotate service.Garden with {
    ID @Common.Text : {
        $value : name,
        ![@UI.TextArrangement] : #TextOnly,
    }
};


annotate service.Plants with {
    garden @Common.Text : {
        $value : garden.name,
        ![@UI.TextArrangement] : #TextOnly,
    }
};
```

I expect to have a Fiori annotation solution that allows me to include a Value Help field during the creation/modification of a Plant. This field should enable the selection of one or multiple Watering Events for the newly created Plant.